# Content change run after javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am using a simple function that before it run a slow function, it put a text in the page with : "loading". But this text only show after the function finish.
I did try to add a css too, but it only run after the function finish.

I put a exemple on fiddle and replace my big function with a sleep function. and the result is the same.

http://jsfiddle.net/9nzg9f6L/5/

here the code I am using in the html page:

```
<div  id='msg'>BEGIN</div>    
<div style="cursor: pointer; color:red;" id='clickme'>click me!</div>
```

here is the javascript code:

```
$("#clickme").click(function(){
    // this code only run after the sleep ...
    $('#msg').text("PROCESSING");

    console.log("text changed");

    sleep(5000);
    console.log("END function");

});


function sleep(miliseconds) {
    var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    while (currentTime + miliseconds >= new Date().getTime()) {}
}
```

I cannot modify the sleep(5000) function. It is a placeholder for proprietary and obfuscated function.

even this:
http://jsfiddle.net/9nzg9f6L/7/

does not work.

Comment: That is ___not___ how you set a timer in JavaScript! A `while` loop that does nothing until the right amount of time has passed? Seriously? Use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout) instead.

Comment: The probme is not the setTimeout.
In my real code I do not call the timer.

I am using plugin function. And I have the same behavior. Also I cannot modify this function.

Comment: Oh, I see... The sleep function was a placeholder for a "Heavy function".

Comment: yes and it is obfuscated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is since javascript is single threaded language, browser just didn't have enough time to alter DOM before "slow" function blocks UI completely. To overcome this situation usually you delay slow operation by some very little time, so that DOM update can finish before bad code starts working:

```
$("#clickme").click(function(){

    $('#msg').text("PROCESSING");
    $('#msg').addClass("message");

    setTimeout(function() {
        sleep(5000);
    }, 50);
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/9nzg9f6L/6/

But of course if it is possible to make slow code asynchronous it would be the best approach in this case. Blocking UI is never a good UX. Also look into [WebWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/basic_usage).

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at my updated jsFiddle which solves your problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/9nzg9f6L/10/

Updated Code

```
$("#clickme").click(function(){

    //Call slow func using a Self Executing func.
    (function(){
        //Create the deferred object to use
        var defObj1 = $.Deferred();

        //Call you slow func
        $('#msg').text("PROCESSING");
        setTimeout(function(){
                sleep(5000)
                defObj1.resolve();
        }, 500);

        return defObj1;  

    })().done(FunctionTwo);
})

//We call this once the Sleep function is done.
var FunctionTwo = function(){
    $('#msg').text("FUNCTION ONE COMPLETED OK..");
};

//Make it slow....
function sleep(miliseconds) {
    var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    while (currentTime + miliseconds >= new Date().getTime()) {}
}
```

Here we make use of a [Self-Executing anonymous function](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/) and [jQuery's Deferred Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) with a `setTimeout` to ensure the slow function executes without halting the entire app. Once done, we can call Function two which in this case simply outputs that the slow function completed.

Comment: I cannot modify the  sleep(5000);
In fact I am not using this sleep function. I am using another function that have the same problem. And I can't modify that because it is proprietary and it is obfuscated.

Comment: @RicardoFerreira: But can't you wrap the "heavy" function in a timeout, as Dayan is suggesting?

Comment: @RicardoFerreira Take a look at my updated answer and jFiddle. It does exactly what you need by making use of jquery's  .deferred object.

Comment: Thanks @Dayan your updated answer works, but the answers from dfsk works too.